# i want to print c# windows form by windows printer

Tags: c#

I want to print c# windows form by printer.when i click print button in form, a print dialog should open just like when  we give any notepad or doc file to print.and i should be able to print the report or invoice.how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use PrintDocument

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=VS.100).aspx

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx if you are interested in dialog options.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.aspx I think you will find what you need there

Answer (score 0):

You can use reporting services to generate a report based on whatever values are on the screen and then use the ReportViewer control to display and print the file.

I can't give you much guidance on how to do that off the top of my head but you could google [winforms reporting services print](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=reporting+services+print&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&safe=active#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=wKH&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=winforms+reporting+services+print&pbx=1&oq=winforms+reporting+services+print&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=10046l11209l0l11891l9l6l0l0l0l5l677l1682l2-4.5-1l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=12c5f54e7a84ee20&biw=1080&bih=686) and see what comes up...