# Printing a document from Windows Form

Tags: c#

I got the this coding  to work,

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern long BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
    private Bitmap memoryImage;
    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
        mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    CaptureScreen();
    printDocument1.Print();

      }
   private void printDocument1_PrintPage_1(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }
```

However This is providing me a screenshot of my Windows form without control box or title bar but still I could see my print button and all those text box. what I want is, to print my document like a form but instead I am getting a screenshot of my form. What should I do here, any suggestions. I have couple of lables, 4 textbox, 1 combobox. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [i want to print c# windows form by windows printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751110/i-want-to-print-c-sharp-windows-form-by-windows-printer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solutions you've tried, they probably rely on the form's Size property.

Try using the form's ClientSize property, which is everything without the control box or title bar, and offsetting the starting location appropriately

Update

Something like this should work:

```
 Bitmap img = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height);
 this.DrawToBitmap(img, this.ClientRectangle);
 Point p = new Point(40, 650);
 e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply tinstaafl. My current code is as follows:

Comment: I am using systeminformation.workingarea for X and Y position. Can u please suggest me How to change or replace this function for removing controlbox and title box.this is the code int x = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.X;
            int y = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Y;
            int width = this.Width;
            int height = this.Height;

            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height);

            this.DrawToBitmap(img, bounds);
            Point p = new Point(40, 650);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p);

Comment: Try using `this.ClientRectangle` instead of creating a new rectangle.  I added a sample to my code.

Comment: @Utkarshsahu Don't post code in comments; it's completely unreadable. If you have code to add, [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18834816/edit) to include it.

Comment: Ohh. Sorry for that, I am new to this and didn't know I could edit my original question.